# How to create a url path to an unknown rails engine polymorphic record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a rails (4) application that embeds 2 isolated engines. One of the engine defines a polymorphic association that targets models in the main application and the second engine.

```
module Engine1
  class Engine1Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :testable, polymorphic: true  
  end
end

module Engine2
  class Engine2Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

class MainAppModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In the Engine1ModelsController views (show/index) I would like to create a link to the associated model. When you know from which domain come the record you can do that:

```
polymorphic_path([main_app, record1.testable])
```

or

```
polymorphic_path([engine2, record2.testable])
```

But here the issue is that I don't know the origin of the model. How I can create a valid url path?

Comment: This is maybe the start of an answer `send(record.testable.class.name.deconstantize.underscore).polymorphic_path(record.te‌​stable)` but it will no work if the engine has been mount with   `as:` option...

Answer (score 1):

I created this helper:

```
module Engine1
  module ApplicationHelper
    def external_polymorphic_path(record)
      engine_name = record.class.name.deconstantize.underscore
      engine_name = 'main_app' if engine_name.empty?
      send(engine_name).polymorphic_path(record))
    end
  end
end
```